# Alternative for Android Studio Theme Editor

Tags: android-studio

As mentioned [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119271605), Google has disabled the Android Studio Theme Editor starting from version 3.3.

They have what seems like an alternative called [Material Theme Editor](https://material.io/tools/theme-editor), but it's only available for MacOS. Is anyone familiar with an alternative that works on Windows?

Comment: That alternative is a plugin for Sketch (https://www.sketchapp.com/). It is not intended for Android Studio and is not a replacement for the Theme Editor. Sketch is a Mac only program and as far as I know there are no alternatives for Windows.

Comment: @amoyer actually the "Material Theme Editor" that I mention in the question is a plugin for Sketch. It sucks that there's no alternative for Windows or Linux.